# Javascript multiple alerts for multiple fields

Tags: javascript, regex, alert

I’m working on a function where I’m gonna check numerous input fields with regexes. However, instead of letting it return false for each of the ”ifs” I’d like it to go through all of the conditions, and then output all of the innerHTMLs at once, from different conditions and input boxes. The text appears under each of the boxes. To give you a hint of what I'm going for.

Instead of having to input something to one box, for getting an error - correcting it, then getting a new error for the next box in the form. I'd like to see that all errors occur on the same button click. (the function trigger from a button).

The code below does not show the errors simultaneously. Is there any way to perform this without a loop? It feels like it should be, but I'm not sure how to move on.

```
 function sum()
      {
          prem1 = document.formular.Uppgift1.value;
          prem2 = document.formular.Uppgift2.value;
          prem3 = document.formular.Uppgift3.value;
          prem4 = document.formular.Uppgift4.value;
          totpr = document.formular.priset.value;


          varning1 = "name";
          varning2 = "address";
          varning3 = "phone";
          varning4 = "phone number has to contain numbers";
          varning5 = "e-mail";
          varning6 = " - This one is not relevant to the input fields and should only show when thus are correct - ";



          var re = /^[\w ]+$/;


            if(!re.test(prem1)) {
            document.getElementById('texterror1').innerHTML = (varning1);
            form.inputfield.focus();
             return false;
             }

             if(!re.test(prem2)) {
            document.getElementById('texterror2').innerHTML = (varning2);
            form.inputfield.focus();
             return false;
             }

             if(!re.test(prem3)) {
            document.getElementById('texterror3').innerHTML = (varning3);
            form.inputfield.focus();
             return false;
             }

             var re = /^(?=.*[0-9])\w{1,}$/;

             if(!re.test(prem3)) {
            document.getElementById('texterror4').innerHTML = (varning4);
            form.inputfield.focus();
             return false;
             }

             if(!re.test(totpr)) {
            alert (varning6);
            form.inputfield.focus();
             return false;
             }

             var re = /^[\w ]+$/;

             if(!re.test(prem4)) {
            document.getElementById('texterror5').innerHTML = (varning5);
            form.inputfield.focus();
             return false;
             }

          else (alert ("Tack för din beställning " +prem1 + "! Här följer de uppgifter vi mottagit om dig. Adress: " +prem2 +" Tel.nr: " +prem3 +" E-post: " +prem4 +" Pris att betala: "  +Discount +" kr" ));{
          return true;
         }
      }
```

*The code was translated on the relevant parts*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `false` in each if statement, create a `var` to handle the error validation setting it to `false` in each failed if statement.

Only at the end of your function should you then return `true` or `false` by checking that `var`.

Comment: I figured something like this, but then I'm not sure of how to structure it to the job properly. Since there's multiple regexes and multiple fields to check. Which essentially is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a single variable *failed* setting it to `false`, only setting it to `true` in any one of the tests fail. But I would also use an array (an object) to store the error messages, using the ids as keys.

I would probably also store the regexes and original error messages in arrays. Using loops would be sensible though, to go through the elements and arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Andrew. As I understand it, nor arrays or loops are mandatory, but good for oranizing the code. But the absolutely rawest way to get this to work, would be removing the "return false;":s and use a single one in the end. However, to get this to work, where should I place it? I'm sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, but.

Comment: Add a variable at the beginning "var failed = false" then instead of "return false" (where you have them currently) just set "failed = true". Then check the value of failed at the end. Of course, you could reverse the logic and name the variable "passed" if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, again. I think I get it. Almost. I'm trying to visualize it before me. However, when checking the value, what should I check it against?

Comment: failed === true ,or perhaps failed === false.

Comment: I'll try this out then. And will probably get back to you with my terror :). I really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Ok, so I've replaced all of the "return false;" with "failed = true", and made the variable. The functionality, is as expected the same as it was from the beginning. However when it comes to the "check", I'm not really sure where in the code I should put it. Should it be within the last condition's {}, That doesn't work so I'm obviously doing something wrong.